# Xamarin Forms using Android Library created in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an android app using android libraries (dependencies in build.gradle), that I want to use in Xamarin Forms app.
I have prepared android class library with dependencies that I need, add it to Android app and it works as should. Now I want to extract library (not app) - .aar file or other type. Then in Visual Studio create android binding library project, add android library (f.e. aar) under "Jars" folder, compile .dll file and in Xamarin Forms project, add reference to .dll and get needed functionality.

Xamarin app accept binding library, it knows android studio library package, tries to execute method, but then problem occurs "Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError". Aar is very light about 40KB, seems like it does not include the library I need, but just reference. Is there a way, that I can have those methods in dll library? I have tried exporting .jar file (weight about 2 MB) but it is also missing classes.

Comment: That's the error I received when some of the classes from library doesn't support the Xamarin architecture yet. So you just need to exclude those classes from library. You can remove those classes by removing there node from library, for that edit the `Metadata.xml` file n remove unsupported nodes, syntax is like `<remove-node ****`